# Which Mobile API to retrieve PayPal transaction details

Tags: paypal

I am trying to build an Android app to retrieve shipping addresses of recent PayPal payments.

Looking at REST Mobile SDK or MPL it seems it's designed to accept payments, but not provide transaction history.

Are there APIs I can use in Android to retrieve transaction details?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) for this.  You can just build the NVP string and POST it to the PayPal endpoint directly.